# Function of the sentence final particle こと in this sentence

Tags: grammar, word-choice, usage, sentence-final-particles, role-language

I am wondering what is the correct way to interpret the こと in this sentence:

> どこかへお花見に行きませんこと。

It is an example sentence found in the book "All About Particles" (page 120). It's described as being basically an alternative way to entice/invite someone to do something together.
If that's true, how does　こと change the meaning and feeling of the sentence, especially when compared to:

> どこかへお花見に行きませんか。
>
> どこかへお花見に行きましょう。

Answer (score 15):

I seriously hope your book explains who (what group of people) would say:

> 「どこかへお花見{はなみ}に行{い}きません**こと**。」 ("Shall we go someplace for flower-viewing?")

Upper-middle-class dames *might* say it, if no one else.  More realistically speaking, though, I would almost exclusively expect to hear it ***in fiction*** as part of the 役割語{やくわりご} (***role language***) for such a female character.

Fiction or real life, this particular sentence will be uttered with a **rising** intonation at its end.

The functions of this elegant, feminine sentence-ending particle are to:

1. Casually make suggestions
2. Casually ask questions
3. Stating opinions

The meaning of this sentence is the exact same as that of each of the two other sentences you listed.

The feeling, however, is quite different for the reason that I have discussed above.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's true and it is placed at the end of a sentence. However we don't use this usage of こと except very elegant and rich ladies.

I have never heard this こと in real life. I wonder if there are people who use this こと now.