# What is the role of ことだ in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

In this sentence: 大丈夫 死にはしませんわ。 少し休めば元に戻ります**ことよ**。

ことよ is is the same as ことだ right?

But what idea does ことだ convey in that sentence?

Comment: お嬢様っぽいキャラのセリフですか？

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Function of the sentence final particle こと in this sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/41644/function-of-the-sentence-final-particle-%e3%81%93%e3%81%a8-in-this-sentence) What @Angelos said. Two important things here characterize the speaker: gender and social class.

Answer (score 1):

Here the copula has been dropped.  How this would be said were the copula not dropped is pushing my active knowledge of Japanese.

But, I'll start by saying this looks like a female speaking to me.  Not just for the use of わ but also for the dropped copulas (two have been dropped).

I believe this could be rewritten as:

> 大丈夫です。 死にはしませんわ。 少し休めば元に戻ることですよ。

The individual is saying,

> It's ok.  I'm not going to die.  If I just take a short break, I'll bounce back.

The idea being conveyed by こと is being used to explain why there's no need to worry.